# Transform route calendar to point to point

Tags: mysql

I have a dataset which basically contains each planned event for our service technicians, like this : [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9afb69543c09a684013ee7ecc3bffe6d)

However, for visualisation purposes, we would like to have it in a Point to Point format.
So basically a line which says who needs to go at what time from what point to which point.
Example of wanted output is also available in above fiddle.

But my knowledge of MySQL is too limited to know how I would be able to achieve this.
Searching the internet has been tedious since the naming of such a conversion is unknown as well.

Comment: Show desired output for shown sample data. Also provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts, not as a table (edit this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8df18f2f777b70a14860b6ebb59c63ba) and provide the link). And specify MySQL version.

Comment: Sorry for not providing the fiddle. Didn't even knew it existed for DB. Added it

Comment: It is available in the fiddle. It groups based on Initials and then uses an order on Date to make rows like From row 1 => Row 2 => Row 3, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT Initials,
       _Date StartDate, 
       Latitude FromLatitude,
       Longitude FromLongitude,
       LEAD(Latitude) OVER win ToLatitude,
       LEAD(Longitude) OVER win ToLongitude
FROM test 
WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY Initials ORDER BY _Date ASC)
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0f005627e65156f504cb5475aa7673cc)